# Changing from string to array not working as expected in Bash

Tags: bash

I want to put the result of the sort method into an array where each cell contains a word. I tried this code but only part of the $file is printed and its not sorted:

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in `ls ${1}` ; do
    if [[ ! ($file = *.user) ]] ; then
        continue
    fi

    arr=(`sort -nrk4 $file`)
    echo ${arr[*]}

done
```

Why isnt this working? How can I do this?

Data file:

```
name1 01/01/1994 a 0
name2 01/01/1994 b 5
name3 01/01/1994 c 2
```

If I run the sort line only (sort -nrk4 $file), this is whats printed:

```
name2 01/01/1994 b 5
name3 01/01/1994 c 2
name1 01/01/1994 a 0
```

When I run the 2 lines above, this is what its printed:

```
 name1 01/01/1994 a 0
```

Comment: @Mat updated with sample

Comment: That works fine here. What version of Bash do you have?

Comment: @Mat version 3.00.15(1)-release .. I updated the question with all the script, do u see anything that could be the cause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for each line of the `sort` output to be put into its own array element, `IFS` needs to be set to a newline. To output the array, you need to iterate over it.

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in $1; do
    if [[ ! $file = *.user ]]; then
        continue
    fi

    saveIFS=$IFS
    IFS=$'\n'
    arr=($(sort -nrk4 "$file"))
    IFS=$saveIFS
    for i in "${arr[@]}"
    do
        echo "$i"
    done

done
```

Alternatively, don't reset `IFS`, don't use a loop for output and the following command will output the elements separated by newlines since the first character of `IFS` is used for the output separator when `*` is used for the subscript in a quoted context:

```
echo "${arr[*]}"
```

Remember, quoting fixes everything.

Don't use `ls` in a `for` loop. If `$1` may contain globbing, then it should be left unquoted. It not, then it should be quoted in case the directory or filename may contain whitespace characters. Ideally, the contents of `$1` should be validated before they're used here.

The comparison operators have higher precedence than the negation operator so the parentheses are unnecessary.

For command substitution, `$()` is preferred over backticks. They're more readable and easier to use nested.

And finally, when variables are expanded, the should be quoted. Also, `@` should almost always be used to subscript arrays.

Comment: @Omar: Oh, *now* I see what's happening. Please see my edited answer.